# Semaphore vs. SQL-Job when trying to remove expired SQL records

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, multithreading, semaphore

I'm using ASP.NET and C# to build some 'Social Network' web site,
while adding posts there are to SQL columns that i fill, the date and time when the post was added, and the date and time when the post is expired (It varies between all kind of posts..)

I want some process that constantly checks the SQL database and remove posts with expired date and time.

I've searched for solution and i understand that the 2 most suitable solutions are Semaphores and SQL Jobs (Correct me if i'm wrong).

I hope you could give me a hint about what's the best solution, if it's not one of the two what is it, and some info about the best solution as well..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just hide posts that have expired based on the current time. For example

```
WHERE ExpiryDateTime > SYSUTCDATE()
```

Then you can clean old posts in the background at any frequency you like. Create a Windows Task Scheduler task that calls a special URL of your website. That URL should perform a database cleanup. This is a very simple and clearly correct solution.

If you don't like Windows Task Scheduler (and who really does like it...) you can use a scheduler lib such as Hangfire or Quartz.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Neither.

- A semaphore is a way of controlling resource use between multiple threads
- An SQL job is a somewhat blunt tool designed to allow db admins to schedule tasks

I would create a separate program 'oldDataDeleter' code up your logic about what you want to delete or archive after how much time and then apply that logic in an atomic way. I would run this as a windows service with a timer, or a console app as a scheduled task

The key is to ensure that the program can run concurrently with itself and only does small atomic changes on a small chunk of data at a time.

You can then fire up multiple instances of this program running at a high frequency.

This ensures don't lock your database with large 'delete all from table X join table Y' statements and that your data is constantly trimmed rather than building up a big overnight job to run.

---

Edit for 'all code must be in a single website project' restriction

There is another solution which in some ways is better and works with your (slightly odd and very much **not** best practice) requirement.

That is to delete old entries whenever you make an insertion. So when you code adds a Post "insert into posts..." it also runs the delete "delete from posts where.."

This ensures that your program is self maintaining. However, you do incur a performance hit when adding posts. Given that a large social media site would be continually adding posts and needs to scale with its users. I don't recommend this solution.

However for small projects which don't need to scale it is neater.

Comment: Yes, but i want all my code to be in my single project of ASP.NET and C# code-behind without any other programs or apps.

Comment: I have edited. but putting everything in one project is a crazy idea